# Difference of executing python script with multprocessing lib and in bash with &-operator

Tags: python, linux, bash, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a python script that makes some DB reads and writes and calculates something - let's say calculating.py. It takes a lot of time depending on the number of DB entries and therefore I thought I could speed it up by multiple executing of the script. I've read some good articles about the multiprocessing lib for python and think that's how I can do it (I've also read about threading).
If I wrap my code of calculating.py in a function, it could be something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def calculate():
    #do something
    print("that's it")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=calculate)
    p2 = Process(target=calculate)
    p3 = Process(target=calculate)
    p4 = Process(target=calculate)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    print('all done')
```

I'm curious, what's the difference to just doing multiple executions as subprocesses in bash, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 calculate.py &
python3 calculate.py &
python3 calculate.py &
python3 calculate.py &
```

I don't have the server setup now, but if I would have 2 CPU cores with 4 threads I would expect a 4 times faster speed as a single execution/process of calculating.py.

How do both ways differ, multiple executions as a subprocess and using the multiprocessing lib, technically which is faster and more efficient regarding resources?

Comment: There's one very important difference in your example. The bash script will not wait for all jobs to complete before exiting.

Comment: True! But they don't need to. They terminate autonomously.

Comment: Is something unclear with my answer?

Comment: @Darkonaut your answer is basically right but you're making the false assumptions. As i said the scripts are terminating autonomously. For each DB entry they look something up and sign it as done so no other process will take the entry up again. I tested it, even without using arguments like in your answer, and the number of processed entries got proportional higher in the same time. Forking the python process vs. forking the whole bash is the learning I've been looking for. Thanks!